# Jekyll gh-pages disappearing site url

Tags: hyperlink, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I built a blog using jekyll and githubpages, and everything was going swimmingly until I added a custom domain name. After adding a custom domain name any link embedded in the website to another part of the blog (except for the homepage) is broken.

i.e. `http://blog.com/about becomes` -> `http://about`
i.e. `http://blog.com/contact becomes` -> `http://contact`

I can type in any of the addresses manually and it works fine, but if I click a link on the website to a post, the about page, or the contact page I get the broken url. How do I stop the site portion of the url from disappearing? Link to blog and its repository below

- [blog](http://solaomi.com)
- [repository](https://github.com/SolaOmi/emerald)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the correct URL, you need to prepend the `site.url` variable.

You can generate the URLs manually in `index.html`:

```
  {{site.url}}/{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}
```

Or use `absolute_url` to have them added automatically (it prepends `site.url` and `site.baseurl`):

```
 <a href="{{ post.url|absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```